# How to get text for multi-page TIFF using Tesseract capi?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using the tesseract capi from Python using ctypes. Everything seems to work well except multi-page TIFFs. I only get text from the last page instead of all the text in a multi-page TIFF.

This is what I'm doing:

```
path = "multipage.tiff"
self.tesseract.TessBaseAPIProcessPages.argtypes = [POINTER(TessBaseAPI), c_char_p, c_char_p, c_int, POINTER(TessResultRenderer)]
self.tesseract.TessBaseAPIProcessPages.restype = c_bool
success = self.tesseract.TessBaseAPIProcessPages(self.api, create_string_buffer(path), None , 0, None)
ocr_r = self.tesseract.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(self.api)
result = string_at(ocr_r) #contains text only from last page
```

Has anyone come across this before or have knowledge of how to resolve this?

I had [opened this as an issue](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1138) in tesseract but apparently this isn't an issue in tesseract command line or API since the command line works fine and gives text for all pages.

Perhaps something else should be called instead of `self.tesseract.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(api)` to get all the text?

Comment: Tesseract's command-line uses `TessTextRenderer` API method.

Comment: hmmm which method would give me all the text? https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/da03e4e9105b6262706d40ef2b4436eae4ebe19f/api/renderer.cpp I don't see any examples of this being used at all. Would appreciate an example if you have knowledge of this.

Comment: It writes the result text to an `<outputbase>.txt` file. Also, check out [APIExample](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample).

Comment: Thank you. But the APIExample you pointed to again uses `TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text `. For the API, I can't write results to a txt file. Instead, I need to return them as a string

Comment: You can use Leptonica's [`pixaReadMultipageTiff`](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/blob/master/src/tiffio.c) to read the multi-page TIFF into an array of Pix, then iterate through the array and process one by one.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string


image = Image.open(path)
image.load()
parsing = ""
for frame in range(0, image.n_frames):
    image.seek(frame)
    parsing += image_to_string(image)
    parsing += '\n'
```

The number of pages is stored in `n_frames`, so you just have to iterate over that number. Hope it helps.